# CSS underline is not highlining the clicked link

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have two links namely "Total Users" and "Users Information". By default "Total Users" is underlined but when I click on "Users Information" the underline moves to that clicked link and then comes back to its default position ie "Total Users". Can someone please help me with this, I want to underline to stay on the link that I've clicked

My HTML code:

---

```
<nav>
  <a style="margin-left: 140px;" 
    routerLink="totalUsers" 
    routerLinkActive="active" id="uno" class="one">
      Total Users
  </a>
  <a routerLink="usersInformation"
   routerLinkActive="active" id="dos" class="two">
     Users Information
  </a>
  <hr/>
</nav>
```

---

My CSS code:

---

```
a {
display: inline-block;
width: 11%;
text-decoration: none;
color: #333;
}

#uno:focus ~ hr {
margin-left: 140px;
}
#dos:focus ~ hr {
margin-left: 22.1% !important;
width: 10.3% !important; 
}

hr {
height: 0.2rem;
width: 6.5%;
margin-left: 140px ;
margin-top: 0;
background: #d9534f;
border: none;
transition: 0.3s ease-in-out; 
}
```

---

Comment: A bit better solution is to add an "active" class to the link which is clicked, focused, or anything you want, and position your underline element relative to that one, either by JS or CSS.

Comment: Wonder if my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this and it worked. Played around with margin-left, initiating margin-left with 0 and then moving it 100px on clicking second link and back to 0 on clicking the first link.
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-mahavira-d0dm4?file=/style.css)

```
hr {
   height: 0.2rem;
   width: 6.5%;
   margin-left: 0;
   margin-top: 0;
   background: #d9534f;
   border: none;
   transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
#two:focus ~ hr {
   margin-left: 100px;
 }
#one:focus ~ hr {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: There I'm not using href. I'm using routerLink and I have problem with 'focus' event too. Could you consider checking with routerLink?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `background-image: linear-gradient()` instead of using `hr` tag which is much easier and you could `add/remove` class to switch the underline.

```js
let one = document.querySelector('.one span');
let two = document.querySelector('.two span')
one.addEventListener('click',function(){
one.classList.add('effect');
two.classList.remove('effect')
});
two.addEventListener('click',function(){
one.classList.remove('effect');
two.classList.add('effect')
});
```

```css
span {
  width: 11%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.effect{
background-image: linear-gradient( #d9534f, #d9534f);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom left;
  background-size: 50% 4px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<a style="margin-left: 140px;" routerLink="totalUsers" routerLinkActive="active" id="uno" class="one">
    <span class='effect'>  Total Users</span>
  </a>
  <a routerLink="usersInformation" routerLinkActive="active" id="dos" class="two"><span>
     Users Information
 </span> </a>

</nav>
```

Comment: When I click on total users the underline has to stay until I click on users Info

Comment: @NaveenPixeler, just noticed that I misread understand what you want to achieve, it think you want to keep the underline after click the link. Updated the code

Comment: I have tried updated code as well, but no expected result. Could you suggest me any other alternative?

Comment: @NaveenPixeler, I think you said either focus event and click won't work, then may be wrap the textContent of the link content with a span and change the span style will work? Check it now? I think it should work, even you are using Angular.js, this way should still work.